# When I pass a $permission into the $gate-define() closure having eager loaded it's related roles -- the roles collection is empty. Why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, acl

I'm essentially recreating Jeffrey Way's example for defining abilities within Larave's Gate/ACL. When I pass a `$permission` into the `$gate-define()` closure having eager loaded its related roles -- the roles collection is empty. If I `dd($permission)` outside of the closure scope the roles are there. If I `dd($permission)` inside of the closure scope they have vanished. Why? Please enlighten me.

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);
    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        dd($permission); // this has the roles
        $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use($permission)  {
            dd($permission); // here the roles are gone -- the key is present but the collection is empty
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }

}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure all permissions have at least one role tied to them?

Comment: This is probably a stretch, but maybe when you use the closure it is reloading the permission through method injection? And since it's injected, it doesn't include the eager loading you originally attached. Seems unlikely but maybe worth looking at the source for this to see if it's injecting.

Comment: From the docs: `All policies are resolved via the Laravel service container, meaning you may type-hint any needed dependencies in the policy's constructor and they will be automatically injected.`

Comment: @ThomasKim I am sure and also the dd() stops the loop on the first permission.

Comment: @funkenstein The `dd` within for loop stops on the first permission. The `dd` within the gate definition does not stop on the first permission. It shouldn't trigger at all until you specifically call it.

Comment: @BrynnBateman I think you may be right... I'm looking into it

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not totally sure why but this solves it:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);
        $permissions = $this->getPermissions();
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            $roles = $permission->roles;
            if (count($roles) > 0)
            {
                $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) use($roles) {
                    return $user->hasRole($roles);
                });
            }
        }

    }

    protected function getPermissions()
    {
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    }
```

It's almost as if the closure was copying the variable before it had any data in it... as if Laravel was lazy loading something even though I was explicitly eager loading in my method. –